# How should I log from a non-root Debian Linux daemon?

Tags: linux, logging, debian, root

I'm writing a new daemon, which will be hosted on Debian Linux.

I've found that /var/log has root only write permissions, so my daemon cannot write log files there.

However, if it writes there, it appears it will gain automatic log rotation, and also work as a user might expect.

What is the recommended way for a daemon to write log entries that appear in /var/log, without having to be run as root?

The daemon is a webserver, so the log traffic will be similar to Apache.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You should create a subdirectory like `/var/log/mydaemon` having the daemon's user ownership

Comment: How about giving write permission to /var/log/mydaemon instead of doing chown?

Comment: Definitely doable, but you have to rely on a common group to achieve that so it's more complex than just setting the proper ownership.

Answer (score 17):

As root, create a logfile there and change the files owner to the webserver user:

```
# touch /var/log/myserver.log
# chown wwwuser /var/log/myserver.log
```

Then the server can write to the files if run as user `wwwuser`. It will not gain automatic log rotation, though. You have to add the logfile to `/etc/logrotate.conf` or `/etc/logrotate.d/...` and make your server reopen the logfile when [logrotate](http://man.cx/logrotate) signals it should.

You might also use [`syslog`](http://man.cx/syslog) for logging, if that fit's your scenario better.

Comment: its better to put the logs in a subdirectory as WiseTechi's answer mentions.  If you have the file in /var/log and the file gets deleted, the non-root process will not be able to re-create the file

Comment: Also the daemon wouldn't be able to log rotate, as it doesn't have permissions to create new files in the logdir.

Comment: Usually the daemon doesn't have to recreate the file, but logrotated renames the existing log and creates a new logfile with the correct permissions. Then it tells the demon to use the new file, which it can since it already has correct permissions.

Answer (score 4):

Two options:

1. Start as `root`, open the file, then drop permissions with `setuid`.  (I don't remember the exact system calls for dropping permissions.)  You'll have to do this anyway if you want to bind to TCP port 80 or any port below 1024.
2. Create a subdirectory like /var/log/mydaemon having the daemon's user ownership, as [WiseTechi said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483781/how-should-i-log-from-a-non-root-debian-linux-daemon#483817).

Files under `/var/log` aren't automatically rotated; instead, rotation is controlled by `/etc/logrotate.conf` and files under `/etc/logrotate.d`.

Answer (score 3):

use the "logger" command

http://linux.die.net/man/1/logger

Comment: logger is bound by the same permission restrictions as any other program. You still need to fix those before using logger.

Comment: @pavon That doesn't seem to be correct, for Ubuntu 18.04 at least. `echo "test" > /var/log/my_log` will fail but `logger "test"` will succeed.