# Where to keep application specific log file

Tags: python, apache, logging, permissions

I am using apache.
If we keep it in `var/www/` folder permission issues is raised.
I am thinking to keep log files in `/tmp/` folder.Is it right place to keep log files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I log from a non-root Debian Linux daemon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483781/how-should-i-log-from-a-non-root-debian-linux-daemon)

Answer (score 2):

No, `/tmp` would not be the right place to save log files.

According to the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS)](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.pdf), the `/tmp` directory serves a different purpose:

> **3.17.1. Purpose**
>   The `/tmp` directory must be made available for programs that require temporary files.
>   Programs must not assume that any files or directories in `/tmp` are preserved between invocations of the program.

The [intent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logfile#Event_logs) of writing log files is the ability to debug errors and keep track of program activity. Therefore, non-persistent logs would be of very little use.

For Logging there is the `/var/log` directory, as being recommended by the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.pdf):

> **5.10.1. Purpose**
>   This directory contains miscellaneous log files. Most logs must be written to this directory or an appropriate subdirectory.

For the rights question I can only refer to [WiseTechi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/483817/1525423), a `/var/log/mydaemon` directory is your way to go.